# Vue.js Should you emit data from popup back to the main window?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I and my co-workers can't seem to agree on what the best practice should be when it comes to Vue and popups.
The question is as follows:

You are on the main window, you get the data from the backend using REST API and you notice an error. To fix it, you go to an edit popup and after hitting save what should happen?

- Should you call the API from the popup?
- Emit the changed data and let the main window call the API?
- ...

Comment: I would use vuex to manage the server interaction through `actions`. The modal would only need to initiate the request. The nice thing is that it keeps the business logic in one place (if you do it for all REST API reqs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very interesting question but I think the truth depends on your whole architecture, implementation and approaches you use.

Say, if you worry about the "separation of concern" you wouldn't give a popup any access to API because its work is to show you some data as a popup, return data, and that's it.

On the other hand, how are you handling errors? What if an error occurs when user works in popup? Where do you show error?

Another question is the usability. For example, if error occurs when you save data, if it's done by the main window, you are going to:

1. Show the error message
2. Make user to click some button again to show the popup
3. Fix a problem and click the Save button in it.

But if you would access API right from popup you would avoid first 2 steps. Another concern is how you handle wrong data.

If you are still in the popup you easily can validate the data and cancel saving (or disable this button at all) but if it's done after the popup is closed it may be too late.

Comment: Aha!! I see what you're saying. It is best if we ask ourselves how we will handle the wrong input/server errors, and then proceed. I have gone with the route of "The main window will close the popup if successful"

Comment: @Hafinator Right, and maybe it's worth to ask your users too :) anyway the idea is to review the workflow from different sides: implementation, error handling, usability etc.